# Pine Script Take Proft / Stop Loss for both Short and Long

Tags: pine-script

I have a back testing script in PineScript that I add to an indicator. It works well for testing the buy and sell signals. I am trying to edit the script for TP and SL for both Long/Short. When using the TP/SL for Long it works, but for the Short side it exits the trade immediately upon entry. I have tried to figure it out the best I can but just can't get it to work. Can anyone help?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Hawkreign

//@version=5
strategy(title="SGA Alert", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, default_qty_value = 100)

// Input options
src = input.source(close, title = "SGA Prime" )

// Long and Short Conditions on the SGA
long = ta.rising(src, 1)
short = ta.falling(src, 1)

// Long and Short Memory
longmem = false
shortmem = false

// Memory Conditions
longmem := long ? true : short ? false : longmem[1]
shortmem := short ? true : long ? false : shortmem[1]

// Entry and Exit Variables
buy = long and not (longmem[1])
sell = short and not (shortmem[1])

// Take Profit and Stop Loss
SL = 0.10
TP = 0.04
LongStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(1-SL)
ShortStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(1+SL)
LongProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(1+TP)
ShortProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(1-TP)

// Long and Short Background color
bgcolor(buy ? color(color.rgb(11, 238, 18)): na)
bgcolor(sell ? color(color.rgb(134, 7, 7)): na)

// Long Entry and Exit
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, when = buy)
strategy.close("LongExit", when = sell)
if strategy.position_avg_price>0
    strategy.exit(id = "close",stop = LongStop, limit = LongProfit)

// Short Entry and Exit
strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, when = sell)
strategy.close("ShortExit", when = buy)
if strategy.position_avg_price<0
    strategy.exit(id = "close",stop = ShortStop, limit = ShortProfit)

plot(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `strategy.position_avg_price` to check your trade direction. Instead, you should use `strategy.position_size`.

```
// Long Entry and Exit
if (buy)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
    strategy.close("sell")

if strategy.position_size>0
    strategy.exit(id = "LC",stop = LongStop, limit = LongProfit)

// Short Entry and Exit
if (sell)
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
    strategy.close("buy")

if strategy.position_size<0
    strategy.exit(id = "SC",stop = ShortStop, limit = ShortProfit)
```